# soql like wildcard numbers?

Tags: soql

I have some data like the following:

```
A-12
A-22
A-33
A-13231231
A-banana
A-cheese
...
```

And I want to get back A-12,A-22,A-33 and other A-numbers in a query. How would I structure the LIKE?

'A-%' would give me back everything.

Comment: This could help => https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/51662/soql-query-to-return-records-with-numeric-values

Answer (score 4):

If you want to search for string which starts with `A-` followed by a digit, you could use `LIKE` on a collection:

```
List<String> fuzzyMatches = new List<String>
{
    'A-0%', 'A-1%', 'A-2%', 'A-3%', 'A-4%', 'A-5%', 'A-6%', 'A-7%', 'A-8%', 'A-9%'
};
List<MyObject__c> records = [
    SELECT ... FROM MyObject__c WHERE MyField__c LIKE :fuzzyMatches
];
```

Another option would be a formula along the lines of:

```
AND(
    "A-" = LEFT(MyField__c, 2),
    ISNUMBER(MID(MyField__c, 3, 1))
)
```

And then just filter on if this formula checkbox is true.

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
SELECT ... FROM MyObject__c
WHERE MyField__c LIKE 'A-0%'
OR  MyField__c LIKE 'A-1%'
OR  MyField__c LIKE 'A-2%'
OR  MyField__c LIKE 'A-3%'
OR  MyField__c LIKE 'A-4%'
OR  MyField__c LIKE 'A-5%'
OR  MyField__c LIKE 'A-6%'
OR  MyField__c LIKE 'A-7%'
OR  MyField__c LIKE 'A-8%'
OR  MyField__c LIKE 'A-9%'
```

**Update**

I like Adrian's answer, but I think SOQL parser ultimately parses the `List` into the above query, without this `OR` statements `LIKE` clauses will not work.

Comment: I think you still need to remove the first value (with no number and just the wildcard).